# « De » est-il obligatoire ou facultatif dans la construction « il n’y a que + substantif + (de) + participe passé ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions

Exemples:

> Jusqu’ici, il n’y a qu’un jeu

…de téléchargé.

…téléchargé.

> Au moment où je vous parle, il n’y a que deux pâtés mexicains

…de faits.

…faits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*De* serait obligatoire si l'attribut précédait son sujet<sup>1</sup> :

> Il n'y a **de** téléchargé qu'un jeu.
> Au moment où je vous parle, il n’y a **de** faits que deux pâtés mexicains.

Dans les phrases de la question, on peut ne pas l'utiliser mais je le recommanderais quand même dans la deuxième phrase car sinon, *deux pâtés mexicains faits* peut être ambigu, *faits* pouvant être compris avec le sens **C.- 1. b)** du TLFi (*Parvenu à un certain degré de maturation*) qui n'est pas celui attendu.

> <sup>1</sup> <sub>Le bon usage §244d</sub>
>  <sub>Le *de* est obligatoire : 1) quand l'adjectif attribut précède son sujet et que le verbe est construit avec *ne ... que*;
>
> [...]
>
> — Majorien. *Cimber vous a battus.*
>
> — L'homme. *Nous n'avons DE battu que le fer de nos casques* (Victor Hugo, La Légende des siècles, V, 8).</sub>